# Show Listile only when it holds data

Tags: flutter, dart

As the question suggests I have a ListView which shows all my "treibstoffData".

**Code:**

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: this.variantData!.treibstoffData!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {}
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            this.variantData!.treibstoffData![index].title!,
            textScaleFactor: 1.4,
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
      ),
    )),
```

As you can see in my Dataset the treibstoffData sometimes contains data & sometimes it doesn't contain data.

```
{
              "bigtitle":"placeholder",
              "title":"placeholder",
              "image":"Assets/Images/AlfaRomeo4C.jpeg",
              "treibstoffData":[
                 {
                    "title":"Benzin",
                    "leistungData":[
                       {
                          "title":"240 PS",
                          "unterscheidungsData":[
                             {
                                "difference":"-",
                                "title":"Coupe/Cabriolet",
                                "wholeText”:"BlaBla"
                             }
                          ]
                       }
                    ]
                 },
                 {
                    "title":"Diesel",
                    "leistungData":[
                       
                    ]
                 },
                 {
                    "title":"Andere",
                    "leistungData":[
                       
                    ]
                 }
              ]
           }
```

& now I was wondering how I have to formulate the if condition so that the list view is only populated with the TreibstoffData in which values are.

Hope I included all the necessary data, if not just write to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the length value at `index` is `> 0` then show the `ListTile` widget else show an empty `Container` widget.

**AS:**

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
this.variantData!.treibstoffData![index].leistungData!.length > 0 ? GestureDetector() : Container()
```

Comment: I think this can't work because the operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.  So in other words you are checking whether the treibstoffData List contains data, but it always does (Benzin, Diesel & andere) & I want to check whether the Benzin, Diesel & Andere itself contain data or not. I think I have to do this with the LeistungsData but can't figure out how, always get an error

Comment: Add your model class.

Comment: ``this.variantData!.treibstoffData[index].leistungData != null`` should work then.

Comment: I have edited my answer check if its' working or not.

Comment: I thought of the solution as well didn't work, do you want the code?

Comment: figured it out it was the != null part, if u update ur answer to "this.variantData!.treibstoffData![index].leistungData!.length >0" I accept it

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a clone of list
2. Filter the list
3. Show the filtered list

```
List  a = List.from(this.variantData!.treibstoffData!. where((element) => element['leistungData'].length > 1));
```

Comment: You'll end up with a list full of empty containers. I'm not sure that it's a desirable outcome.

Comment: I think this can't work because the operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.  So in other words you are checking whether the treibstoffData List contains data, but it always does (Benzin, Diesel & andere) & I want to check whether the Benzin, Diesel & Andere itself contain data or not

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. In that case what you ca do is -> 1) Take a clone of the lisy 2) Filter the new list using the where method 3) Generate items based on cloned list. I have updated the answer.